# Propagation doesnt stop after post api call

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to make a post call when the button is clicked. The API call takes a parameter which I am trying to pass in the onclick method.

**If the column name is xyz or the column status is running the function will not be called.**

Its going to the next method even after stop propagation. What am I doing wrong. 
I need to stop after this post call and refresh the page like in the post call.

```
onClick={() => !(col.status ==="RUNNING") && !(col.name.toLowerCase() === 'xyz') && this.onClickRun(col.name)}>


onClickRun(e,params){

    fetch(`/api/s/${params}/run`, {
        method: 'POST'
    });
    if (!e) e = window.event;
    e.cancelBubble = true;
    if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
}
```

Please help..

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
onClick={() => !(col.status ==="RUNNING") && !(col.name.toLowerCase() === 'xyz') && this.onClickRun(col.name)}>
```

Comment: I did this. but stopPropagation is not working. Its calling the next method.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the event variable. I do not understand why you call your `onClickRun` function with `col.name` as first argument , because the onClickRun function ask an event as its first parameters.

So you have to pass the event of your click, like this :

```
onClick={(event) => !(col.status ==="RUNNING") && !(col.name.toLowerCase() === 'xyz') && this.onClickRun(event, col.name)}>
```